# Would the UK grant a transit visa to a person it deported five years ago?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, deportation

Would a person who has been deported from the UK five years ago be able to transit through the UK on a trip to Grenada?

Comment: If you were deported you have a ten year ban from reentry. What would make you think you would qualify for a transit visa? Impossible!

Answer (score 4):

The eligibility requirements for a transit visa or leave to enter for transit include the applicant being able to satisfy the decision maker that they:
(a) are genuinely in transit to another country outside the common travel area, meaning the main purpose of their visit is to transit the UK and that the applicant is taking a reasonable transit route; and
(b) will not access public funds or medical treatment, work or study in the UK; and
(c) genuinely intend and are able to leave the UK within 48 hours after their arrival; and
(d) are assured entry to their country of destination and any other countries they are transiting on their way there.
With a deportation history, transit through the UK may not be deemed a reasonable route unless it is the only one possible from the country of origin, and it will likely be very difficult to convince the decision-maker that intentions to leave are genuine.